# Regex to extract filename-like text that contains brackets

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract filename-like strings from Usenet subjects. They use quite strange naming strategies, so I decided to just look for filename-like texts like this:

```
r"([\w\-+()'\s.,]{5,}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4})[^A-Za-z0-9]"
```

This worked quite well!

However, sometimes filenames can also contain `[]` while also being itself contained inside `[]`.
For example:

```
[Text]-[Text]-[Filename[Uploader].txt]-[1/23] - "" yEnc 1234567890 (1/23456)
```

Should result in `Filename[Uploader].txt`.

How would I "allow" nested `[]` inside my filename-like text?

Adding it to the inclusion `[\w\-+()'\s.,]` doesn't work, as it matches the outer brackets, which is unwanted.

EDIT:
Some examples of input and output:

```py
('Subject-KrzpfTest [02/30] - ""KrzpfTest.part.nzb"" yEnc', "KrzpfTest.part.nzb"),
('[PRiVATE]-[WtFnZb]-[Supertje-_S03E11-12_-blabla_+_blabla_WEBDL-480p.mkv]-[4/12] - "" yEnc 9786 (1/1366)',"Supertje-_S03E11-12_-blabla_+_blabla_WEBDL-480p.mkv"),
('[N3wZ] MAlXD245333\\::[PRiVATE]-[WtFnZb]-[Show.S04E04.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV.mkv]-[1/2] - "" yEnc  293197257 (1/573)',"Show.S04E04.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.x264-GalaxyTV.mkv"),
("Singer - A Album (2005) - [04/25] - 02 Sweetest Somebody (I Know).flac","Singer - A Album (2005) - [04/25] - 02 Sweetest Somebody (I Know).flac"),
('[PRiVATE]-[WtFnZb]-[00000.clpi]-[1/46] - "" yEnc  788 (1/1)', "00000.clpi"),
("[PRiVATE]-[WtFnZb]-[/More.Bla.S02E01.1080p.WEB.h264-EDITH[eztv.re].mkv] yEnc  2990558544 (1/4173)", "More.Bla.S02E01.1080p.WEB.h264-EDITH[eztv.re].mkv")
```

Comment: Give some example input, as well as some expected output. It is not clear to precisely define a regex without it.

Comment: Does `(?:[^][]|\[[^][]*])*\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}\b` work for you? See https://regex101.com/r/bO9KzC/1 This is a clarification comment, not a solution inside a comment.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I added inputs and expected outputs. @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately that regex did not work for the first case, but maybe with a small change it will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can replace the final `[^A-Za-z0-9]` with just `\b`. This will then not match the character that *follows* the path. This may be important when the path is at the very end of the input with no other character following it.

You can extend your regex with a subpattern that matches text that is surrounded by square brackets. This pattern apparently should also allow for the forward slash, so it would look like:

```
\[[\w\-\/+()' .,]*\]
```

The "normal" pattern could occur before and after such pattern, and there might even be multiple bracketed parts, so that leads to the following:

```
\b([\w\-+()' .,]+(?:\[[\w\-\/+()' .,]*\][\w\-+()' .,]*)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4})\b
```

For your example inputs, see it work on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/14l1KC/1)